# Show that your solution is correct through induction. $5\times(-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

I understand that in the series of $ a_{n} = -a_{n-1}$ where $a_0 = 5$ that it is equal to the closed form of $P(n) =5\times(-1)^{n}$. I'm a bit shaky when it comes to induction but I was wondering how should I approach this after the base step.

I know that I should start by assuming $n=k$ such that $P(n) = P(k)$ but what do I do after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're given 5, -5, 5, -5, etc. and you're trying to prove your $P(n)$ formula.

The induction would go something like this:

**Base Case.** We have that $a_0=5$ and $P(0)=5\cdot (-1)^0=5.$

**Inductive Step.** Here, we want to prove that if $P(n)$ works, then so does $P(n+1)$. We have $P(n+1)=5\cdot(-1)^{n+1}=5\cdot (-1)^n(-1)=(-1)a_n=a_{n+1},$ as desired.

This completes the induction. It's just two steps, and you're done!

In general, induction goes as follows:

- You try to prove a base case (e.g. typically the lowest value for which you want to prove the statement - in this case it was looking at $P(0).$)
- You then claim that for every possible case involving the number $n,$ the number $n+1$ must satisfy the conditions as well.

As a result of these two, using this example, since $P(0)$ works, by both statements $P(1)$ must work. That means that $P(2)$ must work though. And $P(3)$. And... you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Base step: is $a_0=5 \times (-1)^0=5$?  Yes you defined $a_0 :=5$ .

Inductive step: suppose $a_n=5 \times (-1)^n$, we have to show that $a_{n+1}=5 \times (-1)^{n+1}$.

$$a_{n+1}:=a_n \times(-1)=5 \times(-1)^n\times(-1)=5\times(-1)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $n=0$, then it is true that $a_n=5\times(-1)^n$, because $a_0=5=5\times(-1)^0$.

Let $k\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that $a_k=5\times(-1)^k$. Then$$a_{k+1}=-a_k=-5\times(-1)^k=5\times(-1)^{k+1}.$$